# Laravel Users can login despite they are not verified

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum

I am working in a SPA with Laravel sanctum, The frontend was made with Reacts, The client wants that users can verify their emails before they can login. So I made this changes:

Models/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use App\Notifications\VerifyEmail;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasApiTokens;

    .....        
    
    public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
    {                
        $this->notify(new VerifyEmail());
    }
}
```

composer.js

```
....
"require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "babenkoivan/elastic-migrations": "^1.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.9",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    }
....
```

routes/auth.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmablePasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationNotificationController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\EmailVerificationPromptController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\NewPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordResetLinkController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::post('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest');

Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('login');

Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware(['guest']);

Route::get('/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('password.request');

Route::post('/forgot-password', [PasswordResetLinkController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('password.email');

Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('password.reset');

Route::post('/reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('password.update');

Route::get('/verify-email', [EmailVerificationPromptController::class, '__invoke'])
                ->middleware('auth')
                ->name('verification.notice');

/*Route::get('/verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
                ->middleware(['auth', 'signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.verify');*/

Route::post('/email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationNotificationController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.send');

Route::get('/confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'show'])
                ->middleware('auth')
                ->name('password.confirm');

Route::post('/confirm-password', [ConfirmablePasswordController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware('auth');

Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy'])
                ->middleware('auth')
                ->name('logout');
```

routes/api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use \App\Models\User;
use \App\Http\Controllers\TweetsController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController;

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    
    Route::get('/posts',[PostsController::class,'index']);
    Route::post('/posts',[PostsController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('/verify-email/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, 'verify'])
                ->middleware(['throttle:6,1'])
                ->name('verification.verify');               

});
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

app\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerifyEmailController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class VerifyEmailController extends Controller
{   

    /**
     * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    //public function __invoke(EmailVerificationRequest $request)
    public function verify(Request $request)
    {                
        
        try {
            if (Crypt::decrypt($request->route('hash')) != $request->user()->getKey()) {
                abort(400, 'The link is wrong');
            }
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            abort(400, 'The link is wrong');        
        }        
        
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {                        
            return $request->wantsJson()
                ? response([], 204)
                : redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME.'?verified=1');
        }        

        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }
        
        return $request->wantsJson()
               ? response([], 204)
               : redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME.'?verified=1'); 
    }
}
```

The users table already has the **email_verified_at** and **verified** fields, and when I created a user, the **email_verified_at** field is null, then I check the email verification and click the confirmation link, then the user is redirected to the login page and everything is working fine, when I check the database at this point, the email_verified_field is filled with the current date, but the problem is that even if the user doesn't click the verification link or the **email_verified_at** field remainds null, the user can login without problems, I thought that when the user tried to login it would display a message for example: your email is not verified, but this is not happening.
I am using Laravel 8 with **laravel breeze**, But I am using it only as api, the frontend was made with **Reactjs**.
What can I do? Thank you.

Edit: I added this:

```
Route::post('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'store'])
                ->middleware(['guest','verified']);
```

To avoid unverified users to login, and it doesn't work as expected, it displays a message for unverified users, but also displays the same message for verified users!

```
{
    "message": "Your email address is not verified."
}
```

Maybe sanctum is causing this error, I don't know

Edit 2:

Now I added the verified middleware to another protected route:

```
Route::get('/posts',[PostsController::class,'index'])->middleware('verified');
```

Here works properly, for both users, the problems comes when I use the verified middleware in the login route

So strange.

Comment: Seems like you're using  **fortify** for the authentication, did you enable the ``emailVerfication`` feature on you fortify's configuration file?

Comment: Hello, I don't have a fortify's configuration file, I follow the steps to install breeze: composer require laravel/breeze --dev, php artisan breeze:install and php artisan migrate, and the composer.json doesn't have fortify . Thank you

Comment: Can you share your ``web.php`` and ``api.php`` files?, update your question.

Comment: You need to add the middleware `verified` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#protecting-routes

Comment: I edited my question, another error appears

Comment: In another routes the verified middleware works perfect. but the problem is when I add that middleware to the login route, see my edited question

Comment: Jeje, but you don't need to apply that to the login page, how the users are gonna log in? Think about it, remove that from there, you're suppose to apply that after the user is logged in, an then display a message that he needs to be verify the email in order to continue.

Comment: Ok, I understand, I thought that if users were unverified and they try to login a message would appear: "you need to verified your account first" until they verify their account, and if a user is verified then he could login without problems, I think that approach should be the appropiate, but as you mentioned, Laravel allows they to login, and I should to add the verify middleware to others routes. Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately it's laravel's logic. you have to modify login methods in the `AuthenticatedSessionController` to check if the user has already been authenticated in order to log them in manually. theres' some other weird logic like you have to be verifying account from the same browser as you registered. there's just ton to do if you start the project from "breeze" manually

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you´re missing the middleware to ensure the user has verified the email, is simple as adding the middleware `verified`.

```php
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');
```

You can learn more in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/verification#protecting-routes).

Comment: In those kind of routes the verified middleware works perfect. but the problem is when I add that middleware to the login route, see my edited question